# Fixed position navigation arrows aren't working with iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, css-position

I have set up a nice little slider using the following CSS:

```
/*SLIDER
===================================
*/

#full-slider-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#full-slider {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    min-height: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#full-slider .slide-panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: auto;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#full-slider .slide-panel.active {
    visibility: visible;
} 


#full-slider-nav-left
{
  position: fixed; top: 550px; width: auto; margin: auto 0 auto auto;
  left: 0; width: 0; height: 0; cursor: pointer; border: 20px solid transparent; 

}

#full-slider-nav-right {
  position: fixed; top: 550px; width: auto; margin: auto auto auto 0;
  right:0; width: 0; height: 0; cursor: pointer; border: 20px solid transparent;
}


#full-slider-nav-left {
    border-right-color: #BBB;
}

#full-slider-nav-left:hover {
    border-right-color: #999;
}

#full-slider-nav-right {
    border-left-color: #BBB;
}

#full-slider-nav-right:hover {
    border-left-color: #999;
}
```

As you can see, I have set the navigation arrows on either side of the container. They remain fixed as I scroll up and down the page. I'm using the responsive `Skeleton framework` and when I collapse the browser down to mobile size, the arrows work fine. The arrows also work fine on the android platform. However, when I attempt to browse the website on an iPhone, the arrows jump around as I scroll and then disappear.

From what I have read, iPhones have had problems with `position:fixed` in the past, however this was supposedly resolved with iOS 5.

Unfortunately I don't have a live version of the site to demonstrate the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.